# How I post Category post title?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hi all i'm a new of codigniter I create post and join two table I want to show categories title only one in my blog post .but it not folow me.it show many title categories in every post. My Code:

```
COntroller:
    function index(){
        $this->home();
    }
    function home(){
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('slide_view');
        $this->load->view('crumb_view');
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }

    function menu(){
        $this->load->model('tinjeat_md');
        $data["menu_pro"] = $this->tinjeat_md->menu_get();
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('crumb_view');
        $this->load->view('menu_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }
}
Model:
class Tinjeat_md extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function menu_get(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('menu','categories_menu');
        $this->db->join('categories_menu','menu.cate_id = categories_menu.id','left'); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();    }
}
View:
<div class="menu">
<?php foreach ($menu_pro as $value): ?>
    <p class="title_cate">
        <?php echo $value->cate_name_menu; ?>
    </p>
<div class="menu_image">
<?php
echo img(array(
    'src'=>'./images/'.$value->image,
    'width'=>'220px',
    'height'=>'150px'
    ));
?>
</div>
<div class="menu_description">
    <h3><?php echo $value->title; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $value->description; ?></p>
    <p>Prices:<?php echo $value->prices; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

My database:
categories_menu
-id
-cate_menu_name

   menu
    -id_menu
    -title
    -image
    -description
    -prices
    -cate_id
```

Please Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $this->db->join('categories_menu','menu.cate_id = categories_menu.id','left');
```

with

```
 $this->db->join('categories_menu','menu.cate_id = categories_menu.id','inner');
```